# On a stochastic calculus exercise.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am fairly new to these exercises so please bear with me.

I am given that $X_t = 2t + 4B^2_t$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. And I am asked to calculate $d X_t$.

This is confusing to me since standard notation is $d X_t:= X_t - X_0$, but I have a feeling the exercise wants me to apply Ito's formula (Indeed this is what some fellow students of mine did).

To apply Ito's formula I need to somehow write $X_t$ as an Ito process, it is tempting to write

$$X_t = 2\int_0^t \, ds+ 8\int_0^tB_s\, dBs$$ But I don't think 
$8\int_0^tB_s\, dBs = 4B^2_t$. Is this equality true? if so why? (I know the technical definition of Ito integral).

EDIT:
Ito's formula says that (in the formulation I know of) that Given an Ito process $X$ and a function $f(t,x) \in C^{1,2}(R^2)$. Then the stochastic process

$$Y_t = f(t,X_t)$$ is an Ito process and we have that

$$df(t,X_t) = \partial_tf(t,X_t) dt + \partial_xf(t,X_t) dX_t +\frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} f(t,X_t) d [X]_t.$$

EDIT2: If $B_t$ is an Ito process then we can apply Ito's formula and obtain

$$d X_t= 2dt + 8B_t dB_t + 4dt = 6dt + 8 B_t dB_t $$

Comment: Sorry but "standard notation is" **certainly not** "$d X_t:= X_t - X_0$"... What gave you the idea? The paragraph starting with "To apply Ito's formula" is most strange as well. What does Ito say already?

Comment: @Did Thank you for the quick answer! I had the impression that being that an Ito process has the form $X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu_s ds + \int^t_0 \sigma_s dBs$ and notationally we rewrite it as $dX_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$ that this meant that $dX_t := X_t - X_0$. I will edit in Ito's formula in my question.

Comment: Everything before "that this meant" is correct, the formula after it is quite wrong.

Comment: So notationally we can write the integral equation as $d_Xt = \mu_tdt+ \sigma_t dB_t$ but the notation does not mean the same thing as in the original formula? The notation should be taken as a whole, correct?

Comment: The notation $$dX_t=\sigma_tdB_t+\mu_tdt$$ means *exactly* that $$X_t-X_0=\int_0^t\sigma_sdB_s+\int_0^t\mu_sds$$

Comment: Now simply apply Ito to $X_t=f(t,B_t)$ for a function $f$ easy to write down.

Comment: @Did ok, thanks! will report back.

Comment: @Did The only doubt I have is if Bt is an Ito process, then I think I have got it.

Comment: So, your doubt is whether, for $Z=B$, you are able to find $(\sigma_t)$ and $(\mu_t)$ such that $dZ_t=\sigma_tdB_t+\mu_tdt$? Hmmm...

Comment: @Did $\sigma_t= 1$ and $\mu_t = 0$.

Comment: Yup. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did I have another question that I don't think deserves it's own thread (as this one probably did not). Say I am given $dY_t = 3t^2 dt + 2 \sqrt{t}dB_t$ and I am tasked to find $Y_t$, I have been told that If I integrate both sides of my original equation obtaining $Y_t = t^3 dt + (4/3) t^{(3/2)} dB_t$ I get my answer. But what is the justification behind "integrating both sides of the equation" since $dY_t$ is just notation?

Comment: You seem very confused, so much so that I can only recommend to find yourself a good source on the subject and to study it thoroughly. Did you notice that, in your comment, you again mixed the differential elements $dt$ and $dB_t$ with the process $Y_t$? Additionally, you seem to think that $$\int_0^tas^{a-1}dB_s=t^aB_t$$ which is obviously absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Use linearity to get $\mathrm{d}X_t=2\, \mathrm{d}t+4\, \mathrm{d}B^2_t$

Then apply Ito formula to $B^2$:

$$B^2_t=B^2_0+\int_{0}^{t} 2B_s\, \mathrm{d}B_s+\int_{0}^{t} 1 \, \mathrm{d}s$$

$$\mathrm{d}B^2_t=2B_t\, \mathrm{d}B_t+\mathrm{d}t$$

Substitute this to $\mathrm{d} X_t$ to get the final form.

$$\mathrm{d}X_t=2\, \mathrm{d}t+4\, \mathrm{d}B^2_t=2\, \mathrm{d}t+4(2B_t\, \mathrm{d}B_t+\mathrm{d}t)=8B_t\, \mathrm{d}B_t+6\mathrm{d}t.$$